# Looking for a certain synth

Tags: sound

I really want to know what instrument is used for the main lead in the Spice Girl's 'Say You'll Be There', I've been looking for it for ages but with no luck.

Starts at 0:15

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: synth with vibrato and monphonic legato

Answer (score 1):

That is just a high pitched saw wave with note glide on. Any synth can emulate it indistinguishably close.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Yeah I worded that question quite poorly haha!

Answer (score 0):

Reminds me of the Moog sound, like the 'Electric Knife' patch on a Minimoog Model D.

You can hear it here:

https://www.moogmusic.com/products/minimoog/minimoog-model-d#sound-tab

Comment: Is there a way to get a sound similar to this in Logic Pro X? I figured it would be something involving the retro synth?

Comment: Ahhh @Josh if you're just looking to 'replicate' the sound, rather than find the exact instrument it was made on, then that should be a little easier. Maybe you could edit your question to reflect this? There's a lot of great sound designers on this forum that'll be able to help you. There's plenty of free synths with Logic Pro X that would be up to the job I'm sure!

Answer (score 0):

You can mix a sine and a saw on almost any VST. Set the portamento to emulate the glide time you hear. There is vibrato used on held notes, and another LFO modulating the VCF or VCA, of one or both VCOs.

I wish you had referred us to the Worm, by Ohio Players, rather than The Spice Girls!